# Why does declaring returns type bytes memory give a compiler error?

Tags: solidity

If we have the following code:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5;
contract stringsContract {
    function takesTwo(string memory str, uint idx) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory bytesStr = bytes(str);
        return bytesStr[idx];
    }
}
```

Why do we get `TypeError return argument bytes1 is not explicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable bytes memory)`.

The fix was to change `bytes memory` to `bytes`:

```
contract stringsContract {
        function takesTwo(string memory str, uint idx) public pure returns (byte) {
            bytes memory bytesStr = bytes(str);
            return bytesStr[idx];
        }
    }
```

Nevertheless, I'm still curious about the reason of the compilation error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Variable of type 'bytes' and 'string' are special arrays. In first code snippet you are returning an array which is not yet possible in Solidity yet.
You can find docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#bytes-and-strings-as-arrays

When you return in solidity the syntax is like (value_type value_name: optional), what you tried returning bytes which is an array and with name memory, memory itself is spacial keyword in solidity